# This is a duplicate! Your challenge is to close it as such!

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, user-interface, close-dialog

The duplicate selection in the Close dialog is broken. When you pick a duplicate an error appears:

> An error occurred while searching; please try again

and the vote to close button stays disabled.

[image]

That is somewhat inconvenient.

Can this be fixed, please?

Comment: Yeah, there's a fix ready to roll out - just waiting for the build servers to catch up.  Currently only affecting MSO and MSE.

Comment: @KevinMontrose ah, thanks! MSO and MSE were the only sites I checked, so I assumed it was network wide. Thanks for being on top of it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A fix for this has rolled out.

Some stuff behind feature flags wasn't accounted for in the very narrow case of "searching for a duplicate by exact URL".

Comment: What is a "feature flag"?

Comment: Generic term for "some bit, somewhere, that controls whether some code is actually on".  Teams specific things (like Articles), Site specific things (like MathJax), or alpha-y things (like the new editor) are behind feature flags.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Like an experimental browser feature that you have to manually turn on in about:config or about:flags.

Comment: @Shadow obligatory read: https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html (at least for people in software industry, like me)